# What are the possible causes for app deployed on heroku to get crashed?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a nodejs app.It builds successfully but then it crashes.The log says-

> 2016-07-28T11:41:39.150069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>
> 2016-07-28T11:41:39.150070+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:148:18)
>
> 2016-07-28T11:41:39.225296+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>
> 2016-07-28T13:24:05.344533+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=432092788&hub.verify_token=fb_bot" host=fb-121071064.herokuapp.com request_id=77443caa-168e-4428-9f43-9611d8230b9e fwd="66.220.146.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2016-07-28T13:36:37.043656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fb-121071064.herokuapp.com request_id=03ed313b-0930-4e12-8303-1af63446a429 fwd="103.204.168.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2016-07-28T13:36:37.942331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fb-121071064.herokuapp.com request_id=ca3b7c09-e44c-4fbb-97e1-156393b9d483 fwd="103.204.168.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2016-07-28T13:40:46.783907+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fb-121071064.herokuapp.com request_id=928318db-97b2-44c3-ae68-0a5cb20c692f fwd="103.204.168.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Have you tried running it locally?

Comment: Yes it says,error 404..not found!

Comment: it says `2016-07-28T11:41:39.150069+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)` , are you using  some library that is not included in your package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to your repo/github? If it's got a 404 on the localend, then the problem may not be with Heroku. As you're running it locally, try opening up your app on Chrome, then do 'command +shift+ j' to see if there are any error messages. 404 means it can't reach the server...may be something wrong with how your api is written.

Also, I'm going through similar problems right now. This is the closest guide out there that seems to help for heroku issues when you get to it:
http://www.tilcode.com/deploying-a-mean-stack-app-to-heroku/